# Javascript wildcard in IF Function

Tags: javascript

I have a field which has the options below

```
United Kingdom EEA
France EEA
India Non EEA
China Non EEA
```

How can I do an `if` statement that checks whether the field contains `EEA` or `Non EEA`. I have used `==` in my example code which I know is not even close, I just wanted it to be clear.

To my knowledge I can't use `substring` because the `length` will always be different depending on Country and a basic wildcard would still pull back results for `EEA` and `Non EEA`.

```
function DisplayCorrectSections() {
    var SectionSelection = GetFieldValue("Nationality");

        if (SectionSelection == "EEA" ) {
            EnableRtwDocs();
            DisableVisaInformation();
            DisableValidVisaPanel();

        }

        if (SectionSelection == "Non EEA") {
            DisableRtwDocs();
            EnableVisaInformation();
            EnableValidVisaPanel();
        }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  Please note the preview of your question under the textbox that you write the question in.  It will show you whether your question is correctly formatted or not (i.e. how easy it is for other people to read/understand)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf), but you must check for `Non EEA` first, otherwise it will find `EEA` in the `Non EEA` strings too:

```
if (SectionSelection.indexOf("Non EEA") > -1) {
  //contains "Non EEA"
} else if (SectionSelection.indexOf("EEA") > -1) {
  //contains "EEA"
} else {
  //contains neither
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Taking the [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30894277/930393) from @James, you can also do this using regular expressions, which will also test to make sure the text is at the END of the value

```
var matches = SectionSelection.match(/(non )?eea$/i);
if (matches != null) {
  if (matches[1] != "") {
    //contains "Non EEA"
  } else {
    //contains "EEA"
  }
} else {
  //contains neither
}
```

The breakdown of the matching is like this...

- `(non )?` detects whether the letters `non` are there or not
- `eea` matches the letters directly
- `$` matches the end of the line

If there is `non` directly before the `eea` then the `match[1]` will have `non` in it.

The `i` at the end means that it is case insensitive, so it will match `eea`, `EEA`, `EEa`, etc.

Comment: +1 for making me go and check if any countries in the world contained "EEA", which would break my code :)  ([according to this list, they don't!](http://www.nationsonline.org/oneworld/countries_of_the_world.htm))

Comment: Hehe... better to be safe than sorry @James :)  Although as somebody much wiser than me once said "if you make something idiot proof, they'll just make better idiots"

Comment: Thank you gents, very much appreciated!